# C++ Convert wstring to Unicode

Tags: c++, string, rest, unicode

I'm trying to use the rest API and one of the functions has an example like this:

```
uri_builder builder(U("/test.php"));
builder.append_query(U("worker"), U("hello"));
```

I want to use a variable instead of the string literal.
For now I have a std::wstring variable that I want to use but I can't figure out how to use it with the U (unsigned) prefix working on it.

Any suggestions?

I've tried

```
 std::wstring name = L"the_name";
 builder.append_query(U("worker"), U(the_name.c_str()));
```

I've also tried

```
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
    std::string uWorkerName = convert.to_bytes(the_name);
```

My latest failed attempt

```
    std::u32string uWorkerName(workerName.begin(), workerName.end());
```

The last one allowed me to use the API but when the data hit my php page it displayed garbage data such as random numbers and capital letters.

Comment: `U` is a macro, see here for its meaning: https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/basic__types_8h_source.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken your rest api docs are under this url:

https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility_1_1conversions.html

as you can see above, this namespace : `utility::conversions`, proivides various conversion functions which should be of use to you. Example:

```
std::string name = "the_name";
builder.append_query(U("worker"), utility::conversions::to_string_t(name));
```

If you want your name to be composed of wchar_t characters, then above namespace contains also overloads for `utf16string` arguments. From this site:

https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/basic__types_8h_source.html

You can learn that `utf16string` always tries to be string of two byte characters. Under windows it should be `typedef std::wstring utf16string;` while on linux-es probably `typedef std::u16string utf16string;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt #3 looks the closest one. Try this:

```
std::wstring name = L"the_name";
std::string utf8str;
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> utf8_conv;
for (auto &ch : name) utf8str.append(utf8_conv.to_bytes(ch));
```

Comment: 1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt<char32_t,char,struct _Mbstatet>::id" (__imp_?id@?$codecvt@_UDU_Mbstatet@@@std@@2V0locale@2@A)

Comment: Yes, there should be wchar_t rather than char32_t. Edited.